# Pop or Delete a Dictionary item from list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have this list of dictionary items. I want to delete a specific dictionary entry from the list by comparing it with a dictionary item

```
items = 
[
{'label': 'Canary Wharf', 'parent': {'label': 'Canada Water', 'parent': None}}, 
{'label': 'Bermondsey', 'parent': {'label': 'Canada Water', 'parent': None}}, 
{'label': 'Surrey Quays', 'parent': {'label': 'Canada Water', 'parent': None}}, 
{'label': 'Rotherhithe', 'parent': {'label': 'Canada Water', 'parent': None}},
{'label': 'Victoria', 'parent': {'label': 'sth', 'parent': None}}, {'label': 'tth', 'parent': {'label': 'sth', 'parent': None}},
{'label': 'stu', 'parent': {'label': 'sth', 'parent': None}}, {'label': 'tth', 'parent': {'label': 'sth', 'parent': None}}
]
```

I have a variable

```
to_delete = {'label': 'Surrey Quays', 'parent': {'label': 'Canada Water', 'parent': None}}}
```

I would like to do,

```
items.pop(to_delete)
OR
items.delete(to_delete)
```

To get,

```
>>>print(items)
[
{'label': 'Canary Wharf', 'parent': {'label': 'Canada Water', 'parent': None}}, {'label': 'Bermondsey', 'parent': {'label': 'Canada Water', 'parent': None}}, 
{'label': 'Victoria', 'parent': {'label': 'sth', 'parent': None}}, {'label': 'tth', 'parent': {'label': 'sth', 'parent': None}},
{'label': 'stu', 'parent': {'label': 'sth', 'parent': None}}, {'label': 'tth', 'parent': {'label': 'sth', 'parent': None}}
]
```

Comment: `items.remove(to_delete)`

Comment: It shows "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'find'"

Comment: That's why I deleted that comment.

Comment: items.remove(to_delete) is not removing the item.

Comment: My bad, it's removing, I used print(items.remove(to_delete)), instead of printing the lists before and after.

Comment: `to_delete` is a tuple containing two dictionaries, not a single dictionary.

Comment: I edited it, Thanks! @Barmar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are trying to delete a tuple of items. Your `to_delete` is actually a tuple of dictionaries, so to delete them, simply unpack them into separate variables like:

```py
delete1, delete2 = to_delete
items.remove(delete1)
items.remove(delete2)
```

Alternatively, you can keep one variable and accomplish the same by:

```py
items.remove(to_delete[0])
items.remove(to_delete[1])
```

[Remove method in Python](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_list_remove.asp)